# ASP.NET MVC 2 Getting form values without postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an odd question that im not sure has been asked/answered, and im not sure if mvc can do this but:

I have a really massive page/controller which i have been able to code well enough. The user can edit information on this page and wont get it saved to the database unless they specifically say, save. However, there is a list at the bottom of this page that you can add/edit and delete elements. Adding and editing takes you to a different page, and before the page change happens, i want to save the form data to session memory, but i dont know how to access it outside a postback. Can MVC do this?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "Adding and editing takes you to a different page"? *How* does it take you there?

Comment: Adding a new element to the grid takes to an Add page, and edit takes you to an edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible.  There is no way to interact with Session object outside of some form of postback.

You may want to architect your solution as such that you can mitigate the need to go to a different page and return.

The adding/editing portion of your form could instead be handled through asynchronous web POSTS independent of your main form.  JQuery UI's dialog window and UI Tabs come in nicely for sophisticated forms that need CRUD capabilities to other components of your web application.